# update mysql field using CONCAT function?

Tags: mysql, sql

i need a simple query which update mysql field with its value and some modification for example if field have value (3,4,5) i can add (,6) and this just in case it have value and if its NULL then update the field with the ","

i searched web and find mysql function called CONCAT and it Returns the string that results from concatenating the arguments.

i tried this one but this didn't work

```
UPDATE groups SET SubsID = CONCAT(SubsID,",5") WHERE GroupID = 2
```

it return no issue but 0 rows affected and field not updated

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE GROUPS
SET SubsID = CASE WHEN SubsID IS NULL THEN '6'
                  ELSE CONCAT(SubsID, ',6')
             END
WHERE GroupID = 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Add [`COALESCE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) before concatenating

```
UPDATE groups 
SET SubsID = CONCAT(COALESCE(SubsID,''),",5") 
WHERE GroupID = 2
```

Comment: great but when the filed is null it still add the comma i want add the comma only in case the filed is not null otherwise i want add the number only without comma

Answer (score 0):

CSV data in a relational database is a terrible idea. Instead, you should use a [junction table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table) to store *many-to-many* relationships between `groups` and `subs`.

For example

```
CREATE TABLE group_to_sub (
    `GroupID` INT NOT NULL REFERENCES `groups` (`GroupID`),
    `SubID` INT NOT NULL REFERENCES `subs` (`SubID`),
    PRIMARY KEY (`GroupID`, `SubID`)
) ENGINE innodb;

INSERT INTO group_to_sub (GroupID, SubID) VALUES (2, 5);
```

Answer (score -2):

The query is wrong..Try the below one

```
UPDATE groups SET SubsID = CONCAT(SubsID,',5') WHERE GroupID = 2;
```

And make sure that groupid 2 exists

Comment: All you've changed is the quotes which don't make a difference in this case