# concatenate field names in a mysql update with inner join

Tags: php, mysql

Concatenating two field names from different tables using INNER JOIN during UPDATE statement.

I am trying to concatenate two field names in a mysql update statement.

This is what I have so far, needless to say it isn't working, any suggestions would be much appreciated.

```
    UPDATE products 
INNER JOIN sub_categories ON sub_categories.id = products.sub_category 
SET
    slug = replace(trim(lower(sub_categories.subcat_name).(products.product_name)), ' ', '-');
```

Comment: "." is used for concatenate in MySql ? I guess not, use concat() function instead.

Comment: possible duplicate of [update mysql field using CONCAT function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12889965/update-mysql-field-using-concat-function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try as per below-

```
UPDATE products pr INNER JOIN sub_categories sc ON sc.id = pr.sub_category 
SET slug = REPLACE(TRIM(LOWER(CONCAT(sc.subcat_name,'.',products.product_name))),' ', '-');
```

Comment: thanks this worked only it put a . between the field names to instead should be (CONCAT(sc.subcat_name,' ',products.product_name))

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you're trying to concat, but mysql does have a `CONCAT()` function, it's syntax is:

```
CONCAT(sub_categories.subcat_name, products.product_name);
```

For more more documentation: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat